# How to push CPU-heavy tasks from Google App Engine to Google Compute Engine VM instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have CPU-heavy simulation tasks I would like to execute in the following manner using Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine:

1. Simulation task data is submitted through Google App Engine, e.g. by
   executing an API call /runsimulation?param1=...param2=...
2. Inside the GAE servlet, the simulation task is set up and its computational requirements are determined, i.e. what type of compute engine machine is necessary
3. The GAE servlet starts the required VM instance
4. **The GAE servlet somehow transfers the simulation task to the VM
   instance where it is processed**
5. **The GAE servlet is notified when the VM instance has finished. Ideally, it can also receive progress updates during the simulation and display them to the user.**
6. Finally, the GAE servlet receives the simulation result from the VM instance and hands it over to the user. The VM instance is subsequently shut down.

I am having my difficulties with 4 and 5. How can I manage to "push" a computation task to a Compute Engine VM instance from a GAE servlet? And how can GAE and VM instance communicate afterwards?

(While I am experienced with GAE, I am totally new to Compute Engine and have my difficulties entirely grasping the Compute Engine approach to problems like mine)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Save money?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin All I want is to be able to run dynamically constructed, CPU-heavy, parallelizable simulations on the Google Cloud Infrastructure. GAE is not capable of handling these simulations as they will most likeley exceed the 1h GAE time limit and require multi cores to complete in a feasible amount of time.

Comment: Tasks on GAE can run for 24 hours, but it certainly would be more cost-efficient to run them on GCE.

Comment: Note that both GAE and GCE instances can access the same Cloud Datastore, where the tasks and their results can be stored. The GCE instance can update a datastore entity with "progress" status (e.g. "1%", etc.), and the client may periodically retrieve this progress data through a GAE instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to spin up the instance to perform one task the easiest would probably be to provide the task in the form of a startup script as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly)

The GCE instance could report back the status of the work by issuing http requests to GAE.

Alternatively you could communicate between GAE and GCE using  [sub/pub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries). In that case - and unless you assume that the user has the browser open showing a progress page and that this page pulls GAE for updates -  you would probably need to set up a [cron job on GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) to check for finished tasks and act accordingly.